# php-how do i update table fields in the correct row in the database?

Tags: php, database, insert

Right now, I am able to insert the data from the dropdown list in the database. However it is not in the correct row. Like I want the data to be reflected in each of the designated row.

Example, if a student with the admin no of 12344R chose one of the option from the dropdown list, I want the option to be reflected in the database field assigned to the student with the admin no of 12344R.

I came up with the query however, it came out as another row.

```
$complist = $_POST['ddl'];
$query3 = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO student_details SET `company`= ".$complist." WHERE `admin_no`=".$admin.";");
```

Is there another way for me to go about this?

Comment: read through this! http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL query is not right. You should use UPDATE for this

```
UPDATE student_details
SET company = 'company name'
WHERE admin = 'admin_name';
```

You can find more information about UPDATE here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

```
$complist = $_POST['ddl'];
$query3 = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE student_details SET company = '".$complist."' WHERE admin_no = '".$admin."';");
```

Comment: nothing is reflected in the database. THis is how my codes looks like right now. $query3 = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE student_details SET company = '".$complist."' WHERE admin_no = '".$admin."';");

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking to update the database/table you need to use the following

```
UPDATE `student_details` SET `company` = ? WHERE `admin_no` = ?

UPDATE `student_details` SET `company`= '" . $complist . "' WHERE `admin_no` = '" . $admin . "'";
                                        ^                 ^                    ^              ^
```

As well you need to have quotes around around variables denoted by `^`'s

Comment: i've added the quotes with the ' but now, nothing is reflected in the database.

Comment: @Angelica are you inserting or updating?

Comment: @Angelica make sure `admin_no` is in your database as well as the value otherwise it won't update anything.